# Confused figuring out the parameter indicating whether a MOSFET is logic

Tags: mosfet

For example [this](http://info.incomp.hu/NETPDF/IRL3803.pdf) MOSFET in the first page mentioned that it is a logic MOSFET.

But is [this](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf3205.pdf) transistor a logic MOSFET as well? It says VGS(th) is between 2V and 4V. In some forums they claim this is not a logic MOSFET. Im kind of confused what parameter indicates being logic MOSFET.

**EDIT:**

I simulated the following circuit swept the gate voltage from zero to 10V:

[image]

And I got the following plots for Vg(blue plot) and the power(green plot):

[image]

And here is Ids versus Vg:[image]

Doesn't the power plot indicate as long as the Vgs is over 4V we can use this as a switch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

V<sub>GS</sub>th is the **th**reshold voltage where the MOSFET only just barely turns on.
The datasheet for that IRF3205 tells you that V<sub>GS</sub>th is likely to give you a I<sub>D</sub> drain current through the MOSFET of only 250uA.
If you want to use a MOSFET as a 'logic-level' switching device, you need to know that the voltage level applied to the gate by your logic will be able to turn the MOSFET on properly and not just barely.
Probably the best way to do this is to refer to the MOSFET datasheet and look for the
I<sub>D</sub> vs V<sub>GS</sub> graph, like these:
[image]  [image]
The one on the left is the IRF3205, and you can see that it's not particularly good with low V<sub>GS</sub> values. I wouldn't use it as a switch with anything less than 7V available to drive the gate (probably even more).
The graph on the right is for the IRL3803, and you can see that its V<sub>GS</sub> requirement is significantly lower.

Comment: To some point I understand what you explained very well. But Im lost at this point how you interpret: " I wouldn't use it as a switch with anything less than 7V available to drive the gate" What made you to conclude that? I mean at 7V there is a corresponding ID(drain-to-source current) drain in that graph. How does it tell you whether the MOSFET is ON properly?

Comment: Those graphs show typical values; you should look for guaranteed RDS(on) values for the desired VGS.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As you guessed VGS(th) needs to be low enough to be within the Voh level of whatever Logic family and power supply(Vcc) you are using.  4V would be insufficient for 3.3V devices to drive, TTL @5V you might get away with assuming your load current is small.

Comment: So you do not call it logic MOSFET or do you? And 3.3V is between 2V and 4V. You mentioned "4V would be insufficient for 3.3V devices" but what about comparing to the lower limit of the threshold which is 2V? 3.3V is greater than 2V. Should we always exceed or match the upper limit of the VGS(th) to fully turn on the transistor and ignore the lower limit? Hope I made my question/confusion more clear now.

Comment: @dicksonchargepump in order for it to be guaranteed to work your Voh min must be greater than VGS(th) max. The "Logic" description is actually fairly arbitrary.

Comment: Seriously a down-vote with no comment.. tsk tsk.

Comment: @dicksonchargepump The MOSfets you're looking at are monsters - with small fraction of an ohm "ON" resistance. At what point would you say the MOSfet is ON for your application? Take a look at the gate voltage required to get to this point. Trevor is suggesting that this voltage may be higher than your logic control can provide. You'd call such a MOSfet "not-a-logic" MOSfet.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: @dicksonchargepump confused by the second graph,, just plot \$I_{DS}\$

Comment: @Trevor just added, the red plot

Comment: @dicksonchargepump Looks like a switch to me..

Comment: The other answerer claimed he wouldnt use this MOSFET as a switch for less than  7V Vgs. Thats why Im not sure if what I am doing means something.

Comment: @dicksonchargepump he is saying if you want to drive big currents you need more gate voltage. Try reducing that 100R to 1R. you should see a big difference.